# Insert Facebook Like-box into a jQuery modal dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook

I'm trying to use this code to insert the Facebook like-box for my page:

```
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1"></script><fb:like-box href="http://www.facebook.com/pages/xxxxx/xxxxx" width="285" show_faces="true" stream="false" header="false"></fb:like-box>
```

And i'm trying to add it to a jQuery modal dialog, so i'm doing it like this:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $( "#facebook" ).dialog({
        autoOpen: true,
        height: 350,
        width: 350,
        modal: true

    });
    });
    </script>

<div id="facebook" title="Like us">
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1"></script><fb:like-box href="http://www.facebook.com/pages/xxxxx/xxxxx" width="285" show_faces="true" stream="false" header="false"></fb:like-box>
</div>
```

It doesn't display in the dialog, anyone knows what's the problem?

Thanks,

Comment: Does it work if you put it outside the dialog?

Comment: I've created test fiddle if anyone wants to try: http://jsfiddle.net/AYE8A/

Comment: fiddle is pretty useless as you need the fbml xmlns

Comment: Just noticed that it is working, but only in FF and IE (I was checking Chrome)

Comment: I'm using the iframe version of the like box to accomplish that on some sites. There might be a more sophisticated way, but it works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialize the facebook script at the same time the modal is displayed

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#myModal").on("show", function() {
        (function(d, s, id) {
            var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
            if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
            js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
            js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
            fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
        }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
    });
});
```

Anytime you dismiss it and redisplay it you need to reinitialize it.  For example, if your modal has tabs or pagination and facebook is used on page 1 and 2.

```
if(pageId == 1 || pageId == 2) {
    FB.XFBML.parse();
```

Comment: Hi, I've notice that an error occurs when try to call the 'parse()' method on the FB:XFBML Obj. To avoid this, simply wait the JS file file to be loaded with jQuery load, like this: '$('#facebook-jssdk').load(function(){FB.XFBML.parse();});'

Answer (score 0):

To help troubleshoot your question, it might be necessary to see the whole page you want this script to run on.  It might be an issue with not loading the jQuery and jQuery UI (dialog is part of jQuery UI) framework or some other jQuery/Javascript code or CSS that's causing a problem.

Comment: jQuery is working. Dialog is opened on page load.. the ui is also working as I can see the theme I chose, it's just that the like-box is not working within that dialog

Comment: As @Fozzyuw said, it's very difficult to help without seeing the code here.